# Why does the global variable have different values ​in the threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

The global variable g_tmp in A changes. When outputting g_tmp in thread B, it remains unchanged.

```
from time import sleep, time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

g_tmp=[0,0]

def A():
    while True:
        sleep(20)
        global g_tmp
        print(g_tmp)
        print(str(g_tmp[0]+g_tmp[1]))

def B():
    global g_tmp
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        g_tmp[0]+=1
        print(g_tmp)

def main(): 
    threadA = Process(target=A, name='A')
    threadA.start()
    threadB = Process(target=B, name='B')
    threadB.start()  
    threadB.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How to make changes to a global variable visible in all threads? For example, after the first 20 seconds, [10.0] 10 was displayed?

Comment: Because you aren[t using threads, you are using processes.

Comment: Is there a way to change a shared variable when using processes?

Comment: It's possible, but not recommended. Check out the multiprocessing documentation for info on shared state https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. Do you really need to be using multiple processes in this instance?

Comment: In my task, parallelization is necessary for using multiple processors. Does any other mechanism allow doing this on Python?

Comment: If your code represents your task, you don't need multiple processors. But, if you really need multiple processors, check the documentation I linked to. You can use a Value or Array for sharing state https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value.